# Issue with centering and scaling small emojis?

Tags: html, css, browser, render, css-transforms

I'm trying to center an emoji and scale it when it's hovered. I'm running into an issue where, on certain displays, the emoji is displayed off-center. Then when scaling up, there is a jitter in the emoji's position.

The behavior is sometimes different depending on browser zoom and font size. I did try the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142464/how-do-i-horizontally-center-an-emoji) (setting a larger font size and then scaling it down) but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Here's a codepen and videos demonstrating the issue:

https://codepen.io/josh-conley/pen/LYmPjbr

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="emoji-grid">
    <button class="emoji"><span></span></button>
    <button class="emoji"><span>❤️</span></button>
    <button class="emoji"><span></span></button>
    <button class="emoji"><span></span></button>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.emoji-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 6px;
}

.emoji {
  border: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 60px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  transition: transform 150ms ease;
  font-size: 0;
  font-family: Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Segoe UI,Apple Color Emoji,Twemoji Mozilla,Noto Color Emoji,Android Emoji;
  
  > span {
    font-size: 36px;
    width:38px;
    line-height: 1;
    transform: translateY(0.05em) scale(0.5);
    color: white;
  }
  
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

The codepen looks fine on another mac with the same specs as mine, so it's possible that you might not be able to see it there.

Monitor: https://youtu.be/ZKgErMU6pTg

- on my external monitor, resolution 2048 x 1152

Mac: https://youtu.be/_ERKh88uCfI

- on the Mac screen, resolution 1312 x 848

I'm on an M1 v12.4 MacBook. I see this on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: Interesting problem! Thanks for the repro. Well written post. Would benefit from having a clearly posed question statement (you'd have my upvote after that change). I can reproduce on ubuntu-chrome. It might be worth a shot to try wrapping the emoji as text in svg elements and seeing if that has any affect.